# R Bookdown pdf file: how to remove printer marks

Tags: pdf, latex, bookdown

[image: Example]

Can someone advise how to remove the printer marks in the pdf file generated by Bookdown?

Comment: If you are writing a book for Chapman & Hall/CRC, you don't need to remove these marks: https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc/issues/14

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is really a LaTex question. You can try using a different document class, as specified here, though:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latexpdf.html